Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D' to 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody' error in Unity 2D core
I am new to Unity and I am following a tutorial, but when I write the code I get this error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D' to 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody'

The code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movSpeed;
    float speedX, speedY;
    Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        speedX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * movSpeed;
        speedY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * movSpeed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speedX, speedY);
    }
}

How can I fix this?
I tried debugging and rewriting the code and the issue persists.

Well ignoring the fact both types contain the word rigidbody, the computer is telling you that bill is not fred. They are 2 entirely different types, which ever one you put on your gameobject is the correct variable type, and should be the same in both places.

Your rb variable in the PlayerCtrl class has the type for a 3D rigidbody:
Rigidbody rb;

Change it to Rigidbody2D instead:
Rigidbody2D rb;


Thank you so much! (I feel so stupid now)
